# "Cannot resolve symbol 'WifiNetworkSpecifier'"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'WifiNetworkSpecifier'". Import is not found, path in the documentation dont exist.
I tried to rebuild project, invalidate caches.
What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Go to build.gradle(app) and update below

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 29
   buildToolsVersion "29.0.2
}
defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 29
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change tapget API in manifest to 29 level.